# How do I identify a genuine Nagoya antenna?

Tags: antenna

I recently purchased a Nagoya NA-771 that I believe is counterfeit given the overall feel of the antenna. How do I identify a genuine Nagoya antenna vs. a counterfeit?

Comment: The real question is: does it matter? The best is to test. I am here with 2 Baofeng UV-5R and I have the stock and two (probably fake) NA-771. Came in orange package, so probably fake. But I saw a guy on YouTube using that same orange-packed Nagoya to pick up signal from the ISS. I am in a pretty dead zone right now where I only get action on the FRS band 462.xyz MHz, and I noticed that the stock antenna picks up more chatter than the Nagoya fake. But I think that is because the 462 MHz is out of the resonant range of the Nagoya. I need to actually do a test on ~145 MHz and 440 MHz to see what

Comment: In my experience, it absolutely matters.  I obtained two NA-771 antennas, one real and one fake.  The real Nagoya and the stock rubber ducky both outperformed the counterfeit antenna by a huge margin.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow Comments and answers are not for expressing opinions such as "does it matter?". Please study the hamSE [commenting](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and [answering](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) guidelines to see why your answer was deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nagoya has an [official article](https://www.nagoya.com.tw/en/news-31478/%E3%80%8Elatest-updated%E3%80%8FHow-to-identify-the-genuine-and-fake-antenna.html) listing the difference between genuine antennas and counterfeits, please refer to that.

As of their January 15, 2015 update:

- Genuine antennas come in a green bag
- Genuine antennas' bags have well-made rounded corners
- Genuine antennas come with a spacer
- Genuine antennas are straight
- Genuine antennas have a particular printed font (see pictures in the article)
- The QR code on genuine packaging goes all the way next to the Nagoya branding

These are all illustrated in the article, I recommend reading it.

Comment: The counterfeit packaging may also have spelling errors.

Comment: If you're looking for a genuine antenna, start by going to a reputable site like miklor.com or baofengtech.com, and let them direct you to the right product.